# 401 Unauthorized when making a POST request to Microsoft Graph Search API using managed identity with Sites.Read.All permission

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, http-status-code-401, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to make a POST request to the Microsoft Graph Search API endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query using a token obtained from a managed identity with the "Sites.Read.All" permission on the Microsoft Graph API.

However, I am receiving a 401 Unauthorized response. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: how are you using the token? Are you passing it as part of the header? What is the key for that header?

Comment: also, have you tried pasting that token into https://jwt.ms/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in what Oxymoron suggested, "roles" was missing in the bearer token. The solution was to change resource="https://graph.microsoft.com/" to "https://graph.microsoft.com" (without the slash) when requesting the token from the AAD.

Also apparently only delegated permissions work right now on v1.0 Graph Search (Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-query?view=graph-rest-1.0).

The request does work in the Beta version:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/search/query
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "entityTypes": [
          "listItem"
      ],
       "query": {
        "queryString": "contoso"
      },
      "region": "NAM"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear you solve the problem, thank you so much for sharing!